# issue using backpropagation with perceptron

Tags: python, machine-learning

I've been reading Bishop's book on machine learning, and I'm trying to implement the backpropagation algorithm for a neural network, but it's not finding a solution.  The code is below.  I've broken it down into the network code and the testing code.

```
import numpy as np
from collections import namedtuple
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as opt

# Network code

def tanh(x):
    return np.tanh(x)


def dtanh(x):
    return 1 - np.tan(x)**2


def identity(x):
    return x


def unpack_weights(w, D, M, K):
    """
    len(w) = (D + 1)*M + (M + 1)*K, where
        D = number of inputs, excluding bias
        M = number of hidden units, excluding bias
        K = number of output units
    """
    UnpackedWeights = namedtuple("UpackedWeights", ["wHidden", "wOutput"])

    cutoff = M*(D + 1)
    wHidden = w[:cutoff].reshape(M, D + 1)
    wOutput = w[cutoff:].reshape(K, M + 1)
    return UnpackedWeights(wHidden=wHidden, wOutput=wOutput)


def compute_output(x, weights, fcnHidden=tanh, fcnOutput=identity):
    NetworkResults = namedtuple("NetworkResults", ["hiddenAct", "hiddenOut", "outputAct", "outputOut"])

    xBias = np.vstack((1., x))
    hiddenAct = weights.wHidden.dot(xBias)
    hiddenOut = np.vstack((1., fcnHidden(hiddenAct)))

    outputAct = weights.wOutput.dot(hiddenOut)
    outputOut = fcnOutput(outputAct)
    return NetworkResults(hiddenAct=hiddenAct, hiddenOut=hiddenOut, outputAct=outputAct,
                          outputOut=outputOut)


def backprop(t, x, M, fcnHidden=tanh, fcnOutput=identity, dFcnHidden=dtanh):
    maxIter = 10000
    learningRate = 0.2
    N, K = t.shape
    N, D = x.shape

    nParams = (D + 1)*M + (M + 1)*K
    w0 = np.random.uniform(-0.1, 0.1, nParams)

    for _ in xrange(maxIter):
        sse = 0.
        for n in xrange(N):
            weights = unpack_weights(w0, D, M, K)

            # Compute net output
            netResults = compute_output(x=x[n].reshape(-1, 1), weights=weights,
                                        fcnHidden=fcnHidden, fcnOutput=fcnOutput)

            # Compute derivatives of error function wrt wOutput
            outputDelta = netResults.outputOut - t[n].reshape(K, 1)
            outputDerivs = outputDelta.dot(netResults.hiddenOut.T)

            # Compute derivateives of error function wrt wHidden
            hiddenDelta = dFcnHidden(netResults.hiddenAct)*(weights.wOutput[:, 1:].T.dot(outputDelta))
            xBias = np.vstack((1., x[n].reshape(-1, 1)))
            hiddenDerivs = hiddenDelta.dot(xBias.T)

            delErr = np.hstack((np.ravel(hiddenDerivs), np.ravel(outputDerivs)))
            w1 = w0 - learningRate*delErr
            w0 = w1
            sse += np.sum(outputDelta**2)

    return w0

# Testing code

def generate_test_data():
    D, M, K, N = 1, 3, 1, 25
    x = np.sort(np.random.uniform(-1., 1., (N, D)), axis=0)
    t = 1.0 + x**2
    return D, M, K, N, x, t


def test_backprop():
    D, M, K, N, x, t = generate_test_data()
    return backprop(t, x, M)


def scipy_solution(t, x, D, M, K, N, method="BFGS"):

    def obj_fn(w):
        weights = unpack_weights(w, D, M, K)
        err = 0
        for n in xrange(N):
            netOut = compute_output(x[n], weights=weights)
            err += (netOut.outputOut[0, 0] - t[n])**2
        return err

    w0 = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (D + 1)*M + (M + 1)*K)
    return opt.minimize(obj_fn, w0, method=method)
```

When I use the optimize module in scipy (i.e., the scipy_solution() function) to find the network weights, the sum of squared errors gets very close to zero, and the output of the network looks like the data I generated.  When I use my backpropagation function, the sum of squared errors gets stuck between 2.0 and 3.0, and the network output looks almost linear.  Moreover, when I feed the scipy solution for the weights to my backprop function as the starting value, my backprop function still doesn't find the right solution.

I've been stuck on this for a couple of days, so I'd really appreciate any tips anyone has.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def dtanh(x):
    return 1 - np.tan(x)**2
```

should be

```
def dtanh(x):
   return 1 - np.tanh(x)**2
```

Comment: Holy crap.  That's it.  Thanks!